# How exactly does Syntax Highlighting work in IDEs?

Tags: node.js, electron, syntax-highlighting

I was writing my own text editor in Electron using React and I tried to do some basic syntax highlighting. The user writes their code inside a textarea, but there is no way to insert markup inside a textarea so I can't color text that way.

I found [this jquery plugin](https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea) which adds a backdrop behind the textarea so we can put a background color in certain places however I wanted the text themselves to be colored (which can't be done as the textarea is in front of the backdrop).

Any ideas about how other IDEs like Visual Studio Code (also written in electron) pulled this off?

Comment: Take a look at highlight js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches that can work here.

One way could be using a div with a `contenteditable="true"` attribute instead of a textarea. This way you can both write text inside the element and style its contents. Of course this creates its own issues that would have to be dealt with - when to parse the code, how to reposition the caret and more. Depending on the approach, MutationObserver could come in handy.

Another way would be to not use any built-in writing functionalities at all and implement your own. Listen to keyboard events and programatically insert characters. In that case you would also need to implement your own caret, selection etc., which is not easy.

VS Code is open source, so you can actually take a look under the hood and see how the editor is made. They use a completely bespoke editor called Monaco but its source code is in the VS Code repo. [This file is a good start](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/browser/view/viewController.ts).